# QuickBooks API SQL - Querying based in Customer Email Address

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I want to query a customer by email address (Using - select * from customer where Email = 'jdrew@myemail.com') but am unclear which column to reference in Quickbooks to select a customer by Email.  Do I use PrimaryEmailAddr, Address, Email, or PrimaryEmailAddr.Address.

The JSON below has a nested value of Address within PrimaryEmailAddr so I would like clarity on how to extract the value of the email address in QuickBooks API SQL query.

**Find Customer By Email**

```
var customerQueryService = new QueryService<Customer>(qboContextoAuth);
            Customer customer = customerQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("Select * From Customer Where PrimaryEmailAddr.Address = '" + user.Email + "' StartPosition 1 MaxResults 1").FirstOrDefault();
```

**Sample Customer Object**

```
{
    "BillAddr": {
        "Line1": "123 Main Street",
        "City": "Mountain View",
        "Country": "USA",
        "CountrySubDivisionCode": "CA",
        "PostalCode": "94042"
    },
    "Notes": "Here are other details.",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "GivenName": "James",
    "MiddleName": "B",
    "FamilyName": "King",
    "Suffix": "Jr",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "King Groceries",
    "CompanyName": "King Groceries",
    "DisplayName": "King's Groceries",
    "PrimaryPhone": {
        "FreeFormNumber": "(555) 555-5555"
    },
    "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
        "Address": "jdrew@myemail.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to query based on PrimaryEmailAddr instead (someone asked the exact same question as I did), which I found in the post on Intuit's developer forum below.

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004cXDFvKAO/query-customer-by-primaryemailadd